# Replace duplicate rows in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to replace values of duplicate rows in a data.table. Let's say u have

```
A <- c(1,2,3,4,4,6,4)
B <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
C <- c(10,11,23,8,8,1,3)
dt <- data.table(A,B,C)
```

I would like to do: `dt[duplicated(dt,dt[,c(1,3)]),][,2] <- 0` to obtain

```
>dt
   A B  C
1: 1 a 10
2: 2 b 11
3: 3 c 23
4: 4 d  8
5: 4 0  8
6: 6 f  1
7: 4 g  3
```

Comment: `dt[duplicated(dt, by = c("A", "C")), B := "0"]` ? Also, please note that `B` is a character column so assigning 0 to it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It was just to give a reproducible example, i'm working on real and confidential data ;). Thanks you

Comment: @DavidA I think that should be in an answer (either a new one or Roman's), but will leave it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
> A <- c(1,2,3,4,4,6,4)
> B <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
> dt <- data.table(A,B,C, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> C <- c(10,11,23,8,8,1,3)
> dt[dt[, j = duplicated(.SD), .SDcols = c("A", "C")], B := "0"]
> dt
   A B  C
1: 1 a 10
2: 2 b 11
3: 3 c 23
4: 4 d  8
5: 4 0  8
6: 6 f  1
7: 4 g  3
```

... but now seeing David's solution is way more concise...